# Separate edges from canny edge detector

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I want to get a set of all 8-connected paths that are produced by canny edge detection algorithm so I can analyze them independently. Is there a way to do it using OpenCV or any other C++ library without having to implement it myself?

I already have the edges detected, what I need is to find 8-connected paths on the detected edges.

Comment: This question is unclear.  Are you looking for an implementation of the CANNY edge detection algorithm?  Or a post-processing step to identify the paths?  What have you done so far?

Comment: No, I already have the edges detected by CANNY, I want to separate them to analyze each edge independently, in other words, find 8-connected paths on the output of CANNY

Comment: Does cvFindContours() help?

Comment: That's exactly what I need. You should add it as an answer to close the question. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [edge co-ordinates after edge detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828802/edge-co-ordinates-after-edge-detection)