# How to get coordinate of points of each edge using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

I used Canny method to get edges of an image.Obviously,each edge is formed from a series of points.And my problem is how to get coordinate of each point of each edge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [edge co-ordinates after edge detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828802/edge-co-ordinates-after-edge-detection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see what canny outputs you should notice Canny outputs [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat):

```
(...)
Mat canny_output;
Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
cout << canny_output << endl;
(...)
```

What I suspect you want to access is product of [findContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) (vector of vector of [Point](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point)):

```
(...)
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours( src, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++)
      cout << contours[i][j].x << "x" << contours[i][j].y << " ";
    cout << endl;
  }
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Canny method is just a technique of edge detection  but it does not store any information about which edge belongs to which object or something like that.

So, after applying Canny edge, you should use some other technique also so that you can get the information about their coordinates. for example, you can use `findContours()` if you want to get the coordinates of the whole contour.